# Selenium testing number input field (primefaces and jquery)

Tags: jquery, selenium, primefaces-extensions

I use primefaces in my application. There is an inputnumber widget among the extensions.

http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/views/inputNumber.jsf

Under the hood it uses the autoNumeric Jquery plugin, that's why I tagged the question to jquery too.

My problem is when I try to fill the input, selenium IDE won't recognize it as a command. I think it's becouse of the underlying javascript, which deletes invalid (not number) input.

Any sugesstions, workarounds?

UPDATE

I want to use java webdriver or selenium server api. Couldn't make it work with them neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my answer at primefaces forum. Thank you @fenoloco.

http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=35008&p=112415#p112415

```
input.sendKeys(Keys.??);
input.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```